# Defining a a generic method for two subclasses that implement the same interface

Tags: java, generics, set

I'm building a "Contact Manager" in Java.

I have a superclass called "**Contact** which has two base classes; **PersonalContact** and **BusinessContact**.

I have an interface called **Event**, which is implemented by classes **Birthday** and **Meeting**. (Birthday contains one DateTime object while Meeting has two for start and end time).

**PersonalContact** holds a TreeSet of **Birthdays** and **BusinessContact** holds a set of **Meetings.**

Now, in the superclass **Contact**, I want to create an abstract method called "getEventsWithinPeriod()" which will return a TreeSet of all birthdays and/or meetings within a given time span.

The problem is, I don't know how to tell the abstract method, and then the base class methods what to return.

For example, this is the code I used in **Contact**;

`public abstract Set<Event> getEventsWithinPeriod(DateTime start, DateTime end);`

And in PersonalContact;

```
public Set<Birthday> getEventsWithinPeriod(DateTime start, DateTime end){

      Set<Birthday> birthdaysThatAreWithin = new TreeSet<Birthday>();
      //CODE
      return birthdaysThatAreWithin;
```

However, in the compiler, I'm getting an error on `Set<Birthday>`  saying;

"The return type is incompatible with Contact.getEventsWithinPeriod(DateTime, DateTime)"

> What are the proper terms and returns I should be using? Why is my current attempt wrong?

Comment: Why you don't want to continue to use `Event` interface? The main idea of interface to make code clear by defining list of visible method for implementation. Just use `TreeSet<Event>`

Comment: I'm in complete agreement, @Fess--it just seems clear that "getEvents..." returns Events, doesn't it?  The use of generics in this case is just confusing and unhelpful.

Comment: Yes you guys are right, I ended up doing it that way. I didn't have a clear understanding of how the interface could be used to unite both classes as the same type under the banner "Events". Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 3 solutions.

**Solution 1**

First, you can make your classes generic, like so:

```
public abstract class Contact<E extends Event> {
    // ...

    public abstract Set<E> getEventsWithinPeriod(DateTime start, DateTime end);
}
```

And then in your concrete implementation:

```
public class PersonalContact extends Contact<Birthday> {

    public Set<Birthday> getEventsWithinPeriod(DateTime start, DateTime end) { ... }
}
```

This is the best solution, but you have some alternatives.

**Solution 2**

You can change the type of your `birthdaysThatAreWithin` field:

```
Set<Event> birthdaysThatAreWithin = new TreeSet<Event>();
```

as well as change the method signature:

```
public Set<Event> getEventsWithinPeriod(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
```

and return it like that. This restricts you because you can't use the events as `Birthday` instances anymore.

**Solution 3**

You could also change your method signature (in both your abstract and concrete class) to this:

```
public Set<? extends Event> getEventsWithinPeriod(DateTime start, DateTime end)
```

and not change anything else. This has the same problem as solution 2, you won't be able to use the events as `Birthday` instances without casting them.

**Edit:** the downsides to 2 and 3 are that they will require casting. For example:

```
PersonalContact contact = ... ;
Set<Event> events = personalContact.getEventsWithinPeriod(start, end);
// I know all the events are birthdays, but I still have to do this:
for (Event event : events) {
    if (event instanceof Birthday) {
        Birthday birthday = (Birthday) event;
        // Do stuff with birthday
    } // else maybe log some error or something
}
```

With the first solution, you'd have this:

```
PersonalContact contact = ... ;
Set<Birthday> birthdays = personalContact.getEventsWithinPeriod(start, end);
for (Birthday birthday : birthdays) {
    // Do stuff with birthday
}
```

The code looks cleaner and runs better because you don't have to do `instanceof` checks to make sure you don't get a `ClassCastException`. You can also have stuff like this:

```
public static void processBirthdaysFor(Contact<Birthday> birthdayContact, DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    Set<Birthday> birthdays = personalContact.getEventsWithinPeriod(start, end);
    for (Birthday birthday : birthdays) {
        // Do stuff with birthday
    }
}
```

And if you ever have another implementation of `Contact` that has `Birthday` events, you can pass them to that `processBirthdaysFor` method without making any changes.

*However*, if you only need the events and you don't care what the types are in the code calling your `Contact.getEventsWithinPeriod`, then solutions 2 and 3 are *definitely* your best bets. I'd personally just use solution 2 if this was the situation.

Comment: Thanks, I think Solution 2 will be great. My question is though, what practically is the downside? What does it mean that I won't be able to use the events as Birthday instances? What do I lose?

Answer (score 10):

You need to use [`generic Types`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

```
public abstract class Contact<T extends Event> {
    public abstract Set<T> getEventsWithinPeriod(Date start, Date end);
}
public class BirthDay extends Contact<BirthDay> implements Event {

    @Override
    public Set<BirthDay> getEventsWithinPeriod(Date start, Date end) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if `<T>` is good practice. Because `T` should be everything, its like default interface. maybe `Contact<T extends Event>`

Comment: But that means in every other class and method where Contact is used (for example in my ContactManager class which contains a TreeSet of Contacts), I have to change it to Contact<T extends Event>? So I'll have TreeSet<Contact<T extends Event>>  ??

Comment: @Imray you can use `TreeSet<Contact<? extends Event>>` if have a specific requirement like that. This approach removes typecasting that will be required if you use any other approch

Answer (score 0):

Method signature should remain same while overriding any method, you signature should remain same and return Set in PersonalContact class

Answer (score 0):

When using generics, you don't want to explicitly specify the type. You can bound the type, but you don't want to be explicit.

Change your `Contact` method to

```
public abstract Set<T extends Event> getEventsWithinPeriod(DateTime start, DateTime end);
```

and change `PersonalContact` to

```
public Set<T extends Event> getEventsWithinPeriod(DateTime start, DateTime end){

      Set<T> birthdaysThatAreWithin = new TreeSet<Birthday>();
      //CODE
      return birthdaysThatAreWithin;
}
```

That SHOULD get you what you want.

Comment: Don't I need to change the Contact class to Contact<T extends Event> then?